# Web Api [Authorize] not working in IIS 8.5

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

This is the first web API project that we are developing. When the solution is debugging "[Authorize]" is working well, restricting anonymous users. But when when it is published to IIS 8.5 (windows server 2012 R2), that seems be not working allowing any users to fetch records.

Can somebody help me out here. Thanks in advance.

```
[Authorize]
    [Route("api/User/Files")]
    public async  Task<IHttpActionResult>  GetPolicies()
    {
        string email = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.GetUserId();
        AgentDAL agntDAL = new AgentDAL();
        var agnt = agntDAL.Get_agent_info(email);
        Agent agent = agnt[0];
        var policyList = agntDAL.Get_policy_info(agent.AGENCY);


        return Ok(policyList);
    }
```

Comment: Check your web.config.release and find configuration tag there .It might be true for allowanonymous

Comment: how do u Authorize users?

Comment: <authentication mode="Forms" />

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.On the taskbar, click Server Manager, click Tools, and then click Internet Information Services (IIS) Manager.

2.In the Connections pane, expand the server name, expand Sites, and go to the level in the hierarchy pane that you want to configure, and then click the Web site or Web application.

3.Scroll to the Security section in the Home pane, and then double-click Authentication.

4.In the Authentication pane, select Anonymous Authentication, and then click Disable in the Actions pane.

For your ref [Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webServer/security/authentication/anonymousAuthentication)

Comment: When I disable the Anonymous Authentication in the site, all the services require users to be signed in, even the ones specifies with [AllowAnonymous] annotation.

Comment: You can do it in the Virtual Directory level also.Instead at the root elevel

Comment: I copied the web.config file from my machine to the testing server. Then it stated working fine. Probably I had changed settings in the IIS manager

Comment: this is not a good practice .Always check you web.config.release file.This is the file which is effective while you deployed into the server